# Editable TextFields (Remove/Add)

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-layout

**Story**
The user should be able to add new text fields, which will be saved if he opens the App at another time. He should also be able to delete text fields form the view.

**Problem** I was able to implement a button which creates text fields, but I do not know how to "save" them, if he opens the screen at another time again. I also implemented a "delete button" but I do not know how to remove the text field from the view.

**Don't pay attention to** the input of the text fields. I will save that later on with SharedPreferences or in a json file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget
{
@override
_TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin 
{

List<Widget> _phoneWidgets = List<Widget>();

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar
  (
    automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    leading: IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
      onPressed:() { Navigator.pop(context, false);}),
              actions: <Widget> 
    [
      Container
      (
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: Row
        (
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget> 
          [

          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Text(
      '+',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    ),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _phoneWidgets.add(Phone(
          fieldName: 'Phone',
        ));
      });
    },
  ),
  body: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 8),
      children: <Widget>[ Column(
        children: List.generate(_phoneWidgets.length, (i) {
          return _phoneWidgets[i];
        }),
      )]),
);
 }
 @override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
}
} 

class Phone extends StatelessWidget {
String fieldName;
Phone({this.fieldName = ''});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8.0),
    child: TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.1),
      ),
      filled: true,
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
       onPressed: () { 
                    debugPrint('222');
                  }),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.phone,
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 20.0,
      ),
      labelText: fieldName,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
          height: 1.5,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 61, 61, 1)),
      fillColor: Color(0xffD2E8E6),
    ),
    maxLines: 1,
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: If you are saving the data into SharedPreferences, can't you use it to rebuild the fields? And on removal simply remove them from SharedPreferences, remove them from the List you are rendering and use setState to re-render?

Comment: I tried this approach, I can't figure it out. For example how do I know, which Field I have to remove to re-render the list afterwards. Example: User creates 5 TextFields and removes the third.

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you out: Keep a list of text field values (Strings) in state, and build the list view populated with text fields from from this list of strings.

**Handling deletion:** When you click 'delete' for a text field at a specific index in the list, remove the string from your list in state at that same index. Then call `setState()`. This will re-render the list view. Then update your shared preferences entry with this list of strings.

**Handling Addition:** When you click 'add'. Add an empty entry to the list of strings and set state again. Then update your shared preferences entry.

**Re-loading the list on startup:** The next time you start up the app, load the list of strings from shared preferences and set it to your List variable tracked in state. Then build your list view again from this same list of strings.